# Changing xml-file using Ant

Tags: xml, ant

How to change existing xml-file using Ant. 
For example:

```
<test attr="0">
    ...    
</test>
```

to

```
<test attr="1">
...
</test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) see `<attr>` section in particular), eg:

```
<attr path="//test[@attr='0']/" attr="attr" value="1"/>
```

Comment: This is a very difficult decision to change one attribute.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to use `Replace` (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) or `ReplaceRegExp`.